# php scandir produces extra elements (2 dots)

Tags: scandir

Hi,

I have the following files in a directory called content: index.php, page1.php, page2.php and page3.php ONLY.

Then I have this code:

```
 $column = scandir("content");
 foreach ($column as $value) {   
  $stvalue = str_replace(".php", "", $value);    
  echo "<div>$stvalue</div>";
}
```

Nevertheless, this is what I get:

```
<div>.</div>
<div>..</div>
<div>index</div>
<div>page1</div>
<div>page2</div>
<div>page3</div>
```

Whats with the first 2 elements? I dont have files named like that so I dont get it.

Thank you.

Comment: The dot(.) and the double dot (..) are Linux directories.
They are present in each folder. The dot(.) is referencing the current directory while the double dot(..) references the parent directory

Comment: I can figure that out but they should not appear because I dont need them. How can I get rid of them? Besides Im not even on linux but on windows.

Comment: You can filter the special directories. Using array_diff or explicitly check for them with if statement. you can use the glob() function to fetch only .php files for example. This way you avoid the special directories but be careful  as only .php files will be shown. For instance. glob("*.php");

Comment: You mean like with preg_match?

Comment: Some options that I can think about:
glob("*.php"); or
$files = array_diff(scandir("content"), array('..', '.')); or
if($value != '.' and $value != '..') { ... }

Comment: Thanks. I think I will use array_diff(scandir("content"), array('..', '.')); because looks like the shorter way.

Comment: If my answer indeed helped you. Kindly accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.  - is a special directory referencing the current directory.

.. - is also a special directory and its referencing the parent directory.

To remove the special directories I can think of some options:

1.

```
foreach(glob("*.php") as $filename) {
    echo "<div>$filename</div>";
}
```

2.

```
$files = array_diff(scandir("content"), array('..', '.'));
foreach($files as $file) { ... }
```

3.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {    
    if($file != '.' and $file != '..') { ... } 
}
```

All of the above are alternatives. You don't need to use `scandir()` if you use `glob()` and vice versa. `glob()` - expects a pattern. It is possible to also provide it with the path like this:
`glob("[path]/*.php")` - this will list any php file located in path. `glob()` documentation can be found here [PHP - glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: If I use glob then I dont need scandir?

Comment: No. It's an alternative way. Glob excepts a pattern so you can specify to list any pattern you want. See the documentation for it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: I looked at it but I cant figure out how to use it along with scandir.

Comment: You don't use it with scandir. Glob is another way of listing the files in a directory(s). When you use glob. don't use scandir. Its alternative.
Also, see the example I've written in the answer. Try printing the files like this:
print_r(glob("[path]/*.php"));

Comment: Is it possible to specify the directory name?

Answer (score 1):

```
$column = scandir("content");
foreach ($column as $value) {   
$stvalue = str_replace(".php", "", $value); 
if($stvalue != '.' || $stvalue != '..')   {
echo "<div>$stvalue</div>";
}
}
```

Comment: It's better to add some explanations to code only answers.

Answer (score 0):

`.` refers to the current directory. `..` refers to the parent directory.
This is why typing `cd ..` on a command prompt will change to the parent directory. It's been this way in DOS, every version of Windows, Mac OS X, it's not just Linux and UNIX variants.

If you don't want to display them on your page, just skip the first two entries using `array_slice`.